# Let A-Frame run on own webspace

Tags: server, three.js, 3d, aframe

Currently I work with A-Frame.

If I upload the files from [this](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/) example on my webspace, the control through the mobile device orientation gets lost.

How is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser policies require the page to be served over `https` to access the devicemotion API necessary for orientation tracking